# sort a text file by a certain field in place in shell/python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a data log file(say,log.dat) that looks like this(a toy example):

> s('2','3') 102.3993 2992 0.22 0.33
>   s('4','6') 105.44 2993 0.43 0.93
>   s('19','33') 99.93 28992 0.99 0.29
>   ....(similar patterns)

I want to use either bash shell or python to sort the data log file by the 2nd field. which means the output file looks like:

> s('19','33') 99.93 28992 0.99 0.29
>   s('2','3') 102.3993 2992 0.22 0.33
>   s('4','6') 105.44 2993 0.43 0.93

how can I do that with shell script or python in place? maybe it's better to append a tail field indicating the rank of each line( 1,2,3,...) The ultimate goal is to plot the log file in gnuplot by the 2nd field

Comment: Have you tried anything?  this is a relatively easy thing to do using python.  I imagine that it's easy using the shell `sort` command as well. (hint, look at `-n -k` flags of `sort`).  Of course, you can't really do this "in-place").  Not easily anyway.  The best you can do is sort to a new file and write the new file in place of the old one.

Comment: @mgilson - You can sort in place. See `sort -o`.

Comment: @Robᵩ -- That doesn't actually sort in place.  That just writes the output file on top of the input file like I was saying.

Comment: To the user of the sort(1) command, that is precisely sorting in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the bash command line, try the [sort(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) command:

```
$ sort -k2,2 -n -o log.dat log.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ sort -k2 -n inputFile > outputFile
```

where:

- -n, --numeric-sort
            compare according to string numerical value
- -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
            start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)

N.B.  -t, --field-separator=SEP use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition so we are using default field separator